# Python element regrouping based on distance/criteria

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

**Assumptions**
**1.** I have defined a function `foo` that returns a distance value.
**2.** I have a list of groups(also lists in my case) that each contain some number of variables.
**3.** The variables in different groups are distinct, aka no duplicates.
**4.** These groups have length >= 1, (are non-empty),  and <= total number of variables, since no duplicates

**The task:** I am supposed to go through the entire list of variables, check to see if it is 'closest' to its current group using the predefined function `foo`. If it is, it remains in the group, if it is closer to another group, I reassign it to the closer group. If reassignment occurs, I repeat the process for all previous variables to see if the new groups affect their assignments. I continue iterating on previous variables until they are 'well placed' according to foo. Then I move on to the next variable(If the previous iteration changes the groupings, then this iteration checks for distances between the current variable and the new groups).

The main points are: reassignment to groups is based on distance returned by foo and every reassignment will trigger a loop through previous variables. (Previous here should be with respect to the initial ordering of the original groups.)
Consider the example below:

**Brief Example**

```
# In my example, my variables
[[1, 2], [5, 8], [3, 4], [7, 9]]
# Suppose that here we define distance between an element and a list 
# by the difference between the element and the list's average
# Suppose we do not reassign if a number is equally as close to it's current
# group and another group
# and assume an empty set is the same as a set that only contains 0
# the first group does not experience change as its elements are closest to itself
[[1, 2], [8], [3, 4, 5], [7, 9]] 
# 5 is moved to the third group since it's closer to 3.5 than it is to 1.5, 8 and 8
# We then consider the first group again to see if they require reassignment 
# after the group changes. Luckily we do not.
# this is an important step as 1 is now equally close to [2] and [0].
[[1, 2], [], [3, 4, 5], [7, 9, 8]] 
# 8 is moved to last group since 8 is closest to 8
# we would now check to see if the reassignment of 8 
# would cause 1, 2, or 5 to be reassigned, the answer is no here.
[[1, 2], [], [3, 4, 5], [7, 9, 8]]
# We will let 3 remain since it is equally as close to (1+2)/2 and (4+5)/2
# 4 and 5 remain in their current group, and then 7,9,8 remain as well.
# The preferred final result would then look something like:
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [7, 9, 8]]
# Since we require all groups be non-empty, we removed the empty list.
```

For each variable I would have to 'loop' through all of the groups, and for each reassignment I may have to loop through all of the previous variables.

**How would this be done most efficiently?**
Currently I have two methods in mind,
**1.** Looping through all variables without checking previous assignments, and then looping through all variables with the result of the first loop, and continue looping over previous results until no changes can be made for any variable.  (Kind of like the way newton's method is used to find roots)
The concern would be a chance of an infinite loop in the case that a few variables keep moving back and forth, and possibly a very long run time.

**2.** Checking previous variables for every time a new reassignment is made.
Also exists the possibility of an infinite loop. In addition, if the first variable is reassigned, we can move on to the second, but if the last variable is reassigned, we may have to check all the variables multiple times. This could be very costly.

**Additional Comments:** I am trying to 'cluster' variables with python(2.7) in a similar fashion to what SAS does with its default `maxeigen=1` **varclus** procedure with the `hierarchy` option. I have tried various methods provided by the packages **sklearn** and **scipy**, but the resulting clusters are different than those outputted by the sas procedure. Any suggestions towards this would be helpful as well, otherwise this is just additional information not related to the question of element reassignment itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same in R and used following based on SAS documentation "The iterative reassignment of variables to clusters proceeds in two phases. The first is a nearest component sorting (NCS) phase, similar in principle to the nearest centroid sorting algorithms described by Anderberg (1973). In each iteration, the cluster components are computed, and each variable is assigned to the component with which it has the highest squared correlation. The second phase involves a search algorithm in which each variable is tested to see if assigning it to a different cluster increases the amount of variance explained. If a variable is reassigned during the search phase, the components of the two clusters involved are recomputed before the next variable is tested. The NCS phase is much faster than the search phase but is more likely to be trapped by a local optimum."
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_varclus_sect001.htm
Variable reassignment in varclus happens in two steps

1. Based on squared correlation - squared correlation of (squared loadings) variables from cluster(i) to all other clusters. Variables will be reassigned to clusters with which it has maximum squared correlation

**Squared-correlation of variable(i) with cluster(j) can be defined as:**
  (vector having correlation of variable(i) with variables in cluster(j) %*% first principal component of cluster(j)/sqrt(first eigenvalue of cluster(j))^2

**Here:** %*% matrix multiplication

2. Search based reassignment - this step is costly as it searches if given variable can be reassigned to some other cluster so that total variance explained increases

Comment: Yeah, I ended up implementing this in python a few months ago. 
Getting my result to match SAS results was difficult but the logic of my python code should match the logic as described by the SAS documentation that you provided above. Thanks :)

Comment: @asheketchum Would I be able to see the Python? Is it on GitHub? Would be great if I could

Comment: @joshlk I haven't really used GitHub sorry. Which part of the code are you looking for exactly? The clustering part?

Comment: @AsheKetchum the clustering part which replicates the SAS varclus method. There dosn't seem to be anything that replicates it in python. You could use pastbin.com or a GitHub gist. Thanks!

Comment: @joshlk I'm not sure if I'm supposed to share the code itself. Is there a way to message you directly? Perhaps I can try to explain how I did it, and maybe you can come up with a better version.